# How Can I add the First Record To a Telerik Radgrid

Tags: gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have built an ASPX form to enter data on various organizations.  Each organization will have multiple contacts with various contact types.  I may have a name and need to designate the contact type as Name, and an email with contact type of email.  I am doing this because I only want certain types of contact information added.

So I added a Telerik Radgrid to handle the contact data.  Now the problem is when I try to add a new Organization, since there is no contact data to populate the Grid it does not appear on my form.

Below is the ASPX code for the Radgrid:

```
<div id="radgrid2">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                     OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource"
                     OnItemDataBound="RadGrid2_ItemDataBound"
                     OnItemCommand="RadGrid2_ItemCommand"
                     AllowAutomaticInserts="true"
                                              >
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                    <MasterTableView
                         DataKeyNames="ContactTypeID"
                         CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                         AllowPaging="true"
                         PageSize="5">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Contact Type" UniqueName="ContactType">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlContacts"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    </Columns>

                    </MasterTableView>

                </telerik:RadGrid>
            </div>
```

So how can I add the first record to an empty nested RadGrid?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with this simple fix.  All I needed to do was set the RadGrid DataSource to an empty string with this line of code

RadGrid2.DataSource = string.Empty;